# Need Software/pseudo printer to redirect print jobs to other printers and keeping copies of said jobs

Tags: windows, printing

I need a virtual printer capable of doing this at the same time:

1. Print to PDF (automatically placing PDFs in some user accessible folder, without asking the user).
2. Forward the print job to another -configurable, could be remote or local - printer.

I.E., some virtual printer that routes print jobs to another printer and keeps PDF copies of said jobs.

I don't care if there are more than one software involved. For instance, a virtual printer that send each job to multiple printers at once could do the job too. (I could then install 2 printers, the "routing" one and a PDF printer, and configure the routing one to send the job to the real printer and the PDF printer at the same time)

any ideas? (Free software is a bonus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i haven't used it for a long time but as far as i know [**PDFCreator**](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator) is capable of this and some more:

- automatic saving
- opening, mailing or printing PDF after creation
- script-execution before and after creating the PDF
- create (and also im- & export) profiles for different settings
- translated into 25+ languages
- it is at least partly FOSS
- and [many other features](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/features)...

***but take care during the installation, because reportedly the installer tries to install some adware!***

Answer (score 0):

You can do stuff like this really easily on Linux.

Set up a Linux box, install and configure Samba, use a PDF creation script to generate a PDF file and put it in their home directory (and/or anywhere else you want, perhaps a permament-ish archive?) and then in the same script pass it off to some other physical network printer via the local printing system (cups, lpd, etc).

Comment: I know ;-) I use linux too, but the PC is a Hotel Font Desk's and it uses windows, and it must use the local printer, a remote printer is not an option. :-(